# How to update all data that appears in datagridview in a column c#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have this code:

```
var groups = netflow.OrderByDescending(x => x).GroupBy(x => x).Select(x => x.Key).ToArray();
var rank = netflow.Select(x => Array.IndexOf(groups, x)+1);
```

I want to update all data that appears in datagridview with rank variable. I already try this code:

```
int[] rankResult = rank;
for (int ii = 0; ii < rankResult.Length; ii++)
{
     string empNumb = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["empNumb"].Index, ii].Value.ToString();
     RC.updateRank(rankResult[ii], empNumb, period, year);
}
```

Comment: Please tell us whats your problem? Showing code without a question makes it really hard to guess

Comment: @lokusking i want to update all data that apperars in datagridview in a column with rank variable sir. You can see int[] rankResult = rank, there's error.

Comment: What kind of error do you get? NullReference-Exception or TypeMismatch? Can you even compile?

Comment: Cannot implicitly convert type'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<int>' to 'int[]'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
I know that the problem is a different type of variable, int and int[]. I have no idea anymore to correct it @lokusking

Comment: Try `int[] rankResult = rank.ToArray();`

Comment: Cannot convert method group 'ToArray' to non-delegate type 'int[]'. Did you intend to invoke the method? there's error sir @lokusking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to change your code to something like:

```
var rankResult = rank.ToList(); // Or int[] rankResult = rank.ToArray<int>();
for (int ii = 0; ii < rankResult.Length; ii++)
{
     string empNumb = dataGridView1[dataGridView1.Columns["empNumb"].Index, ii].Value.ToString();
     RC.updateRank(rankResult[ii], empNumb, period, year);
}
```